# Publishing Service Invalid Schema Installed Upgrade from version 0 to 1

Tags: publishing-service

I am trying to follow up https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/889655 but as soon as I modify - publishing service would not start with the following error:

```
"[Error] Unable to start service: "Invalid schema version installed. Upgrade from version 0 to 1

Please run the 'Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.exe schema upgrade' command to upgrade"

Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Exceptions.InvalidSchemaVersionException: Invalid schema version installed. Upgrade from version 0 to 1

Please run the 'Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.exe schema upgrade' command to upgrade

at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.PublishingExtensions.EnsureLatestSchemaInstalled(IApplicationBuilder builder, ILogger logger)

at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILogger`1 logger, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime, IServiceInformation serviceInformation) in C:\BA\fb80de5dfd630cfc\src\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host\Startup.cs:line 87"
```

I executed schema upgrade --force prior to restarting a service with new configuration but still, the error is popping up.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to execute first `Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host schema downgrade –-force` and then execute `Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host schema upgrade –-force`

For me worked well few times.

Comment: I executed schema upgrade --force prior to restarting a service with new configuration but still, the error is popping up.

Comment: Did you try to execute it with `schema downgrade --force` and then again `schema upgrade --force` as I already mentioned above?

Comment: Thanks for double-checking to ensure I noticed the schema downgrade --force, and this make the trick! Thanks so much